# My mail function isn't working?

Tags: php, email, web, sendmail

The following code snippet is not working.

I checked my `php.ini` file, but it looks fine.

It's not returning any errors.

I have heard something about using something called `sendmail`.

I am using a Mac.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">CLICK</button>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        error_reporting(); 
        $to  = 'philipnagel511@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'subject';
        $message = 'text';
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: user <philipnagel511@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: server <nipdeliveries@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use something like swiftmailer or phpmailer?

Comment: im not sure how to use swiftmailer or how to insert it into my existing code akshay

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an email server that PHP is configured to use.
[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail) is a guide for how to set this up. Postifix which is mentioned comes standard with Macs and can be also installed on Linux.